# Vibrating sound coming from air condition vent when turned up high?

Tags: honda, ac

When I turn my ac up high, I hear a vibrating sound coming from one of the vents.  It vibrates more if I turn it up higher.  What could this possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

The vent fan blades may be hitting something, such as part of the fan housing or a bottle cap.

Comment: I thought about that.  I will have to check.